# Swift Generic Implementation of protocol throws error `Type does not conform to protocol`

Tags: swift, generics, factory-pattern

I have 3 model classes:

```
protocol IncludedItem {
    var id: Int { get }
    var text: String { get }
}
```

```
protocol PrimaryItem {
    associatedtype Included: IncludedItem

    var id: Int { get }
    var canClose: Bool { get }
    var canDelete: Bool { get }
    var canSend: Bool { get }
    var includedItems: [Included] { get }
}
```

```
protocol QuoteItem {
    var id: Int { get }
    var isSelectable: Bool { get }
}
```

Then I want to use the factory pattern for Item creation. This is my factory protocol:

```
protocol QuoteItemFactory {
    associatedtype Item: PrimaryItem

    var delegate: QuoteItemFactoryDelegate? { get set }

    func create(item: Item) -> QuoteItem
}
```

And this is an implementation of the factory protocol:

```
class OrderQuoteItemFactory: QuoteItemFactory {

    weak var delegate: QuoteItemFactoryDelegate?

    func create<Item: PrimaryItem>(item: Item) -> QuoteItem {
        let viewModel = OrderQuoteViewModel(quote: item)
        viewModel.delegate = self

        return DefaultQuoteItem.quote(id: item.id, viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}
```

But then I always get the following error:
`Type 'OrderQuoteItemFactory' does not conform to protocol 'QuoteItemFactory'`.

What am I doing wrong? I know if I use it like this:

```
class OrderQuoteItemFactory<Item: PrimaryItem>: QuoteItemFactory {

    weak var delegate: QuoteItemFactoryDelegate?

    func create(item: Item) -> QuoteItem {
        let viewModel = OrderQuoteViewModel(quote: item)
        viewModel.delegate = self

        return DefaultQuoteItem.quote(id: item.id, viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}
```

I know that using it like this will work perfectly. But I'm wondering why I can't use the generic with the function declaration.

Comment: Just a side question… do you need to use protocols here? Is it absolutely necessary? It might be but I just wanted to check first.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes for unit testing purposes we're using protocols

Comment: But it seems like there is no behaviour defined by the protocols. Only properties. Apart from the Factory. I don’t see any benefit of using protocols to define sets of properties. It would make more sense to have these as structs. You can still test structs with different properties without needing protocols.

Comment: It doesn't conform because your implementation function is different than the protocol defined one

Comment: These are slimmed down protocols for the purpose of readability here in the question on stack overflow. The model protocols have much more behaviour in our project. So no protocols are not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you change your factory protocol to this?

```swift
protocol QuoteItemFactory {

    var delegate: QuoteItemFactoryDelegate? { get set }

    func create<Item: PrimaryItem>(item: Item) -> QuoteItem

}
```

I noticed (at least from your example) that you don't really need an `associatedType`, so you could just make the function itself generic, instead of the protocol.

Comment: This actually works, thanks! Never thought I had to define it in the function declaration like that in the protocol.

Comment: It really depends on your needs. If you have multiple functions (and/or properties) in a protocol and all of them use same generic type, you should use `associatedType`, otherwise you could just make the function itself generic.